# Any idea how to make this loop

Tags: php, loops

I need to create a loop like this via PHP ( a WordPress `WP_Query` ) , 
it's like `one` large item then `two` small items and then `two` small items again , and then , `one` large item and so on...
Here's the plain HTML :

```
<div class="swiper-slide big">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide normal">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide normal">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide big">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide normal">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide normal">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide big">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

The `<div.item>`s are post elements.
I couldn't find any pattern to make such loop , one option is to use a counter and compare each number , but it's not a stable way to do this.
could anyone help please.

f.n : the `.swiper-slide` DIVs are just wrappers , every time the loop runs , we only have a `<div.item>` and we need to group these `.item`s with the pattern i explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a "counter", you could use a modulo equation.

In your example, there are 3 rules we can apply:

1. One big, then four small
2. The first and third small start a new parent div
3. The second and fourth small end the parent div

Assuming that your posts are in an array, with numbered keys, you can use this:

```
foreach ($itemArray as $key => $item) {
    $modulo = ($key+1)%5;
    switch($modulo) {
        case 1:
            echo <<<END
                <div class="swiper-slide big">
                    <div class="item"></div>
                </div>
            END;
        break;
        case 2:
        case 4:
            echo <<<END
                <div class="swiper-slide normal">
                    <div class="item"></div>
            END;
        break;
        case 3:
        case 0:
            echo <<<END
                    <div class="item"></div>
                </div>
            END;
        break;
    }
}

//Closing possible open div
$arrCountModulo=count($itemArray)%5;
if($arrCountModulo==2||$arrCountModulo==4) {
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: The most reasonable answer so far <3 , let me try

Comment: I've not tested this yet Lol ... And not sure about using the Heredoc in case statements ... But we'll see how it goes Lol

Comment: Thank you , it seems to be close to working , the only problem i can see , is it shows repeated elements , see this fiddle  http://codepad.org/YEJLKjdv

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot some breaks ... I'm editing my answer now

Comment: Wow , i have to say you're a genius, thank you so much, you're a life saver <3

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated example where you pass the items as an array :

```
<?php

function myloop($items) {

    $i = 0;
    $isBig = array( true, false, false);

    while(sizeof($items) > 0) {
        if($isBig[$i]) {
            echo "Big ! ", array_shift($items);
            echo " \n";
        } else {
            echo "Normal... ", array_shift($items), " ", array_shift($items);
            echo " \n";
        }
        $i = ( $i + 1) % sizeof($isBig);
    }
}

myloop(array("item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7","item8","item9","item10"));

?>
```

Cli output :

```
$ php loop.php
Big ! item1
Normal... item2 item3
Normal... item4 item5
Big ! item6
Normal... item7 item8
Normal... item9 item10
```

Comment: yes , the problem is how to put `.item`s in them , as i said in the footnote , `big` and `normal` are just wrappers

Comment: it's a `WP_Query` object

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter variable(for this example, `$i`) to track how many div sections are printed. Your code should be like this:

**Edited:**

Based on your requirement, I've updated my answer.

```
$itemArray = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q");
$arrLength = count($itemArray);

for($i = 0; $i < $arrLength; ++$i){
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        if($i != 0){
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide big">
            <div class="item"><?php echo $itemArray[$i]; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide normal">
        <?php
    }else{
        ?>
            <div class="item"><?php echo $itemArray[$i]; ?></div>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works , as the Stretch's anwser, Thank you both <3 , saved my life tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
$bignormal = 0;
for ($i=0;$i<$whatever;$i++) {
   if ($bignormal>0) {
       echo "normal";       
   }
   else {
       echo "big";
   }
   $bignormal++;
   if ($bignormal>2) {
      $bignormal = 0;
   }
}
```

Not the greatest piece of code in the world, but it works.

### Explaination:

`$bignormal` is (by default) set to `0`. `$bignormal` is thus not greater than `0`, so we echo `big` and increment `$bignormal`.

Next iteration, `$bignormal` is `1`, thus being greater than `0` so we echo `normal` and increment `$bignormal`.

Next iteration, `$bignormal` is `2`, and thus is greater than `0` so we echo `normal`. However, when we increment `$bignormal` it is now greater than `2` (with a value of `3`), so the final `if` statement sets `$bignormal` to `0`.

Next iteration `$bignormal` is set to `0`, so thus it's not greater than `0`, so thus we echo `big` and increment `$bignormal` yet again.

Etc.

### In conclusion...

Nothing that complicated, and could probably be compacted down heaps with some better logic :D

Comment: Please read the footnote , `big` and `normal` are just wrappers , `.item`s are the elements we have access to with each loop run

Comment: Yeah, I figured. You should just be able to echo anything that you want though, not just `big` or `normal`. I was just using them as placeholders.

Comment: in your code , with every loop run it prints a `big` or `small` , but if you look at the pattern , for example on the `3rd` run , it should only print `<div.item>` or on the `5th` and so on...  , But i really appreciate your time <3